# I have image in <picture> tag, it is showing in IE but not in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: html, css

These images are working properly in IE but not in Chrome and firefox. Below is the HTML code

```
<div class="megamenu-featuredcontent eG1-3Col">
    <div>
        <div class="block imageblock eG1Col ">
            <div class="">
                <picture class="image-normal-100 ratio16-9" data-alt="Image Networks Mega Menu" data-orgwidth="2400" data-orgheight="1350">
                    <source srcset="/ui/images/blank.png" data-srcset="scaledimages/networks-event-crowd-with-hands-original_750x422_90.jpg, scaledimages/networks-event-crowd-with-hands-original_1500x844_85.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1180px)">
                    <source srcset="/ui/images/blank.png" data-srcset="scaledimages/networks-event-crowd-with-hands-original_720x405_90.jpg, scaledimages/networks-event-crowd-with-hands-original_1440x810_85.jpg 2x" media="(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px)">
                    <source srcset="/ui/images/blank.png" data-srcset="scaledimages/networks-event-crowd-with-hands-original_970x546_90.jpg">
                    <img src="scaledimages/networks-event-crowd-with-hands-original_970x546_90.jpg" alt="Image Networks Mega Menu">                      
   </picture>
    </div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Please create a fiddle if you may please.

Comment: I think i have followed it

Comment: So your "Internet Explorer" is Edge 13 or greater …?